# Is there a way to know all the line numbers where the control flow went?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Can we generate a report indicating the line number where the control went in visual studio? I am having a really hard time detecting the flow of control since the program I have made is more than 6000 lines and that is creating a huge problem debugging it.

Is there any feature in Visual Studio or any code which can help me here? I want my program to complete all the processes and I want be able to see the line-by-line control flow later when the program stops executing.

I have tried the Break-point Debugging and it is not helping much because I want the program to keep on running, complete all the process and then show me a report or something of that sort.

Comment: try Debug menu > Windows > Call Stack. [StackTrace Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8) can be used to get the call stack information programmatically

Comment: Exactly @Slai. What you are talking about is known as *Call Stack*